# Некорректное отображение символов в ответе на post-запрос при парсинге сайта, использующего js

Tags: java, парсер

Пытаюсь парсить сайт, где данные подгружаются при помощи js. Каждый раз, когда я меняю данные в строке расширенного поиска на сайте, серверу отправляется post-запрос. При помощи Network Monitor я определил заголовки и url запроса. В ответ возвращается json. Но когда я повторяю такой же запрос у себя в коде, в ответ возвращаются непонятные символы, будто что-то с кодировкой.

```
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client=new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://tgstat.ru/channels/list");
    post.addRequestHeader("Host", "tgstat.ru");
    post.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    post.addRequestHeader("Referer", "https://tgstat.ru/");
    post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    post.addRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    post.addRequestHeader("DNT", "1");
    post.addRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    post.addRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    post.addRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    try {
        int statudcode1 = client.executeMethod(post);
        String charset=post.getResponseCharSet();
        String postRespose = post.getResponseBodyAsString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: То, что меня интересует. А именно, содержимое List]

[image: То, что я получаю в ответ]

В идеале мне нужно получить значение list. Помогите пожалуйста советом и примером.

Comment: попробуйте убрать header acceptencoding

Comment: попробуйте убрать вот эту post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

Stranger in the Q, спасибо!
Убрал строку

```
post.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
```

Всё работает.

Comment: соответственно сервер думал что Вы хотите zipнутый ответ